# Silly question - I forgot how this is called "!n"

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, permutations, combinations

I'm terribly sorry, I know it's a dumb question, but I completely forgot, and google didn't turn up anything.

$n! = 1 * 2 * ... * n$ and thats how many orderings there are of $n$ people in a straight line.

That's fine.

But I'm 100% certain theres a $!n$ operator too. if i remember correctly, it means how many permutations there are where everyone must move. no one can stay at the same place. I think.

What is it called?! I'm going crazy here.

Comment: Factorial, I'm not sure about the !n though

Comment: !n is not factorial. n! is factorial.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: Were you going crazy, or were you just deranged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking of **derangements.** This is a permutation on $n$ symbols with no fixed points.

Comment: Thanks! thats what I meant!

Answer (score 0):

$!n$ is called subfactorial.
It is used to denote the derangements.
Like,$!3=2$